# Is it a common practice to include the version of an API into the rest interface itself?

Tags: api

I was looking for the current version of the github API, but it seems to be omitted.

https://api.github.com/

I am personally considering to add a new field to my own API, but I wonder whether that is a common practice or should be done differently.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Many APIs include a version number in the url of the service. Some examples:

- https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json
- https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me/adaccounts
- https://vision.googleapis.com/v1/images:annotate?key=YOUR_API_KEY
- https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.29
- https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/vision/v1.0/analyze
- https://www.europeana.eu/api/v2/opensearch.rss?searchTerms=Rembrandt

However many people on the Internet argue that this is incorrect because it violates REST/HTTP specifications; ["embedding of API version into the URI would disrupt the concept of hypermedia as the engine of application state"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/398564/741249). It’s more appropriate to [use the Accept header to request a particular version](http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2011-07-03-nobody-understands-rest-or-http). For the latter people suggest to use a Vendor MIME type, for example something like `Accept: application/vnd.mycompany-api-v3+json`

Nevertheless, the reason why many API designers do include an API version in the url is because it's easy to implement and debug (clearly visible which version you are using).

*Side note:* in our organization we recently decided to support both a versionless endpoint that always point to the latest stable version of our APIs, as well as an endpoint with a version specification. This allows users to choose if they want to commit to our latest API (which may require making changes when a newer version is released), or to connect to a fixed API version (which may become deprecated over time).